# True/False: a claim in Calculus

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $a_n, b_n$ be two sequences that satisfy:

$a_n\leq b_n$ for infinietly different values of $n$ and $a_n\geq b_n$ for infinietly different values of $n$ then $a_n, b_n$ converge to the same limit.

I think it is not true.
Let's take $a_n=(-1)^n$, $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ then
$a_n\leq b_n$ for all the odd $n$ and $b_n\leq a_n$ for all the even $n$. However both sequences diverge.

Is it a good counterexample?

Comment: That would be a counterexample for the claim, yes.  What about if you strengthened the hypothesis to include that both sequences converge?

Comment: Yes, that's a good counterexample. However, if you have the additional hypothesis that each sequence converges, then you can show that they have the same limit.

Comment: Ha, @Alan we had the same idea!

Comment: Yeah, if we assume that both converge then we can use that $lim a_n\leq lim b_n$ and $lim b_n\leq lim a_n$ and therefore   $lim a_n=lim b_n$ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample is correct. If, however, we assume that $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge then we can show that they have the same limit. To do so, first pick two subsequences $a_{n_k}$ and $b_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively such that $a_{n_k}\leq b_{n_k}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit of both sides (and noting that all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit) we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k} \leq \lim_{k\to\infty}b_{n_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$$

With similar reasoning we can show that $\lim_n a_n \geq \lim_n b_n$ and therefore conclude that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to the same limit.